# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object4

Tags: apex

I am getting null pointer exception in the following code.

```
if(renderSaveButton && srmObjId!=Null){
   try{
        system.debug('renderSaveButton is-->'+renderSaveButton);
        system.debug('srmObjId is-->'+srmObjId);
                   // Get Parameters
                   Boolean Srmobjupdate=false;
                ID proID = srmObjId ;
                pse__proj__c proj;
                pse__project_task__c projTask;
                if(proID.getSObjectType() == pse__proj__c.getSObjectType()){
                    proj = new pse__proj__c(ID=proID);
                }
                if(proID.getSObjectType() == pse__project_task__c.getSObjectType() ){
                    projTask = new pse__project_task__c(ID=proID);              
                }

                if(Locationid != null && Accountid != null ){
                    if(proj!=null){
                        proj.pse__Account__c = Accountid;
                        proj.gsd_Location__c = Locationid;
                     }   update proj;
                     if(projTask!=null){
                        projTask.pse__Project__r.pse__Account__r.name=Accountid;
                        projTask.gsd_Location__c = Locationid;
                        update projTask;
                     }             
   }
   }
```

> [58]|pse__Proj__c.getSObjectType()
>   )|ENTRY|[58]|com.salesforce.api.fast.System.compareObjects(Object,
>   Object)
>   )|EXIT|[58]|com.salesforce.api.fast.System.compareObjects(Object,
>   Object) 
>   _ENTRY|[61]|Id.getSobjectType(Id)
>   )|_EXIT|[61]|Id.getSobjectType(Id)
>   )|_ENTRY|[61]|pse__Project_Task__c.getSObjectType()
>   1|_EXIT|[61]|pse__Project_Task__c.getSObjectType()
>   )|_ENTRY|[61]|com.salesforce.api.fast.System.compareObjects(Object,
>   Object)
>   )|EXIT|[61]|com.salesforce.api.fast.System.compareObjects(Object,
>   Object) )|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[69]|System.NullPointerException: Attempt
>   to de-reference a null object

Comment: Can you include the error message and point out which line it's happening on?

Comment: How are you relating the pse__Project__c record to the projTask record?

Comment: For Object Proj it is working fine.when i tried to do for Projtask if(projTask!=null)here iam getting the error

Comment: @srini - that line`if(projTask!=null){`  will not produce that error....please post the related debug log section

Comment: @srini - see updated answer

Comment: @srini - It would be helpful if you could post the correct and complete code as well as the debug log in entirety as I have a strong feeling you hare missing something important...as from the debug you posted it looks like the error is thrown on the compare but it should have never made it there if the items you executed getsobjecttype on were null...

Comment: May be you are checking for two different data type here  :                              
`if(proID.getSObjectType() == pse__proj__c.getSObjectType())`

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

From the debug logs it looks like `proID` may be null thus `srmObjId` is null.

When you debug srmObjId does it indeed show null?

**OR** the running user does not have access to the pse__project_task__c object / package - check the licenses

It is hard to tell from the log formatting and missing parts but I am leaning toward no access to the pose__project_task__c object by the running user as I think that is what the debug log it saying

You debug log does not match the line you said in your comments or your code as posted so...

That cannot be the complete code as there is no catch block.

Either way, debug out all the values you are executing getsObjecttype on and see which one is null. may be quicker that the back and forth here

<strike>Taking a stab at it though:</strike>

if the `renderSaveButton` is a boolean value and this is a controller and you have not explicitly set the value to true or false and instead are just using

```
 public boolean renderSaveButton {get;set;}
```

`if(renderSaveButton && srmObjId!=Null)`

will cause a dereference null object error

where

```
if(renderSaveButton == true && srmObjId!=Null)
```

will not

Comment: renderSaveButton will come as true as iam setting it in constructor ,